# How to read data from xml file in Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

I am new to Angular and I want to read a specific node from the XML file. 
example:
let's say I have an XML file emp.xml

```
    `<employees>
    <employee>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Iqbal</name>
    <address>xxxxx</address>
    <contact>xxxxxx88xx</contact>
    </employee>
    <employee>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Anil</name>
    <address>xxxxx</address>
    <contact>xxxxxx88xx</contact>
    </employee>
    </employees>`
```

now I want to read this whole file. and then I want to extract specific node i.e name of the employee. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in plain old JS:

```
const myXML = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<xml></xml>', 'text/xml');
```

If you wanted to get your first employee then, you can get it like this:

```
const firstEmployee = myXML.getElementsByTagName('employee')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
 let xml_content= `<employees>
    <employee>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Iqbal</name>
    <address>xxxxx</address>
    <contact>xxxxxx88xx</contact>
    </employee>
    <employee>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Anil</name>
    <address>xxxxx</address>
    <contact>xxxxxx88xx</contact>
    </employee>
    </employees>`;
    
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml_content, 'text/xml'); 
    let firstEmploye = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('employee')[0];
```